# Formatting coordinate with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, cllocation, nsnumberformatter

I'm attempting to format CLLocation coordinate with NSNumberFormatter in order to obtain something like this 44°32'52.90" N from number 44.325290.

I've tried to set a number formatter (looking [documentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Number_Format_Patterns)), but doesn't work. 
I'm not able to specify another separator like ' and .

Code:

```
- (NSNumberFormatter *)coordFormatter {
    if (coordFormatter == nil) {
        coordFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [coordFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"#0.0#####"];
        [coordFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@"°"];
        [coordFormatter setPositiveSuffix:@"\" N"];
    }
return coordFormatter;
}
```

With this code I obtain a string like 44°325290" N

Someone can help me?

Comment: 4°32'52.90" N isn't equal to 44.325290.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSString` with format instead or extends your own formatter.